# Windows 10 boot loop after update

Tags: windows-10, boot, bsod, safe-mode

Last week I got my new laptop and installed Windows10 with anniversary update. Some days it worked really well, however, during the last reboot of the system windows installed some updates and since then my laptop gets a bluescreen before it shows the logon screen:

[image]

So I tried to start windows in safe mode, but there is no way to accomplish that, as the corresponding menu entry is not shown:

[image]

I also tried every other option in this menu and nothing solved my issue. So the question is, is there another way to start windows 10 in safe mode? Or another way to uninstall the latest updates or do I have to reinstall windows?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have been reaching Safe Mode in Windows 10 by pressing Shift-key upon clicking Re-start inside Windows 10 on some of the alternatives there. This will lead to the Advanced options Menu, like you have given there above, but, instead of your UEFI options, I see there now Start-up options, inside where you can find the Safe Mode options on a next-next Menu.

OK, understand, that you may have a slight difference on the Menu due to the BlueScreen and not getting inside Windows 10, but let's see, if some method would pop-up applicable.

Anyway, I do not remember getting into Safe Mode with F8 since Windows 7, nor seen any big harms caused by it, but maybe it's still somehow in use on some cases ... OK, also checked, and neither any of the Shift+/Ctrl+/Alt+/AltGr+F8 did work for this on my F-S laptop with Windows 10 1607.

Edit: OK, I found a possible solution for this in here -> http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/17159-safe-mode-add-boot-options-windows-10-a.html -> Option two , and then later reversing -> Option three . Sorry, do not now have possibilities to check this in practice, but may come back tomorrow ...  In the meantime you may check this, first getting into -> Advanced options Menu -> Command prompt .

Edit2: OK, works like a charm ... Slightly tricky just copying the example commands' parameters into the cmd, but if writing as straight no problem.  Hope you can get the bcdedit-procedure done upon/after the BlueScreen. And, after all done/ready and machine re-started, I think the burdening real problem correction procedure, driver or alike chase will begin. And, note, the login PIN may have been changed into the real password ...

Edit3: Of course, you could also try the System Restore option on the Menu to a possible good restore point backwards, but it may result in an adventure ...

Answer (score 1):

F8 or Shift+F8 while it is starting it's boot can force it to boot into Safe mode.

The other option would be using a recovery drive or disk to boot.

If both of those options fail, then unfortunately I think the only other option would be to reinstall Windows 10.  After which you should definitely create a boot/recovery disk.

Comment: The last time I tried F8 for booting I killed the motherboard of my Dell 9550 (Just was repaired today http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19666394) and booting with an bootable usb-stick also only shows this options...

Comment: Have you attempted to use the system restore feature?  it is possible that the update you downloaded was either only downloaded partially or it became corrupt and that is causing the loop.

Comment: @boindiil - Pressing F8 didn't kill the motherboard.  Of course F8 or Shift-F8 would present you the Advanced Startup with Windows 8+

Comment: @ZackScaringello I already tried the system restore but didn't work either.

Comment: @ramhound Did you read my link? Others had the same issue too. What else should it be if the motherboard dies after starting with F8 pressed and interrupting the boot process?

Comment: @boindiil - I didn't know I was suppose to read it...You can't brick a laptop by pressing a key.

Comment: @Ramhound - Until last week I had the same opinion as you, But unfortunately it seems this is a dell bug...

Answer (score 0):

After updating, I had the same issue. All I had to do to fix it was to select "Use different operating system" from safe mode (f8 on bootup, even when stuck in a bootloop) and select Windows 10 (there was another one on top of that without a name, presumably because of the update). It worked for me, it might work for someone else who searches it up (this is where I ended up when I googled the problem, so I hope this helps someone).