# PC not booting, loading forever

Tags: windows-10, boot

[image]

All of a sudden, my Dell XPS 13 PC stopped booting and would load forever at the [spinning dots screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBegr.png). Sometimes my PC would reach this screen:[image]Safe mode works fine(that's how I got the screenshot).

### Attempts to fix

I have tried using Startup Repair, but that didn't change anything. The Dell Pre-boot System Assessment says everything is working fine.

See Edit #5

### Question

How can I fix my computer without losing any data?(I don't have backups)

**Edit:** This is not a duplicate of [Windows 10 boot loop after update](https://superuser.com/questions/1122396) because the cause of the problem in that question is different from mine. Also, that user wants to go into safe mode, I already can do that. Also in that question, the computer crashes whereas mine just keeps on loading forever.

**Edit 2:** I tried turning off my wireless keyboard and mouse and trying to boot up the computer mentioned by @YisroelTech, but it didn't work.

**Edit 3:** To make things clear, I have not updated recently.

**Edit 4:** I tried the video mentioned by @CodeIt but it didn't work.

**Edit 5:** I tried System Restore using an automatic restore point, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Take a look at this video [on how to fix boot loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2f-GorXWkoc)

Comment: Do you by any chance have a wireless mouse or keyboard plugged in the machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 boot loop after update](http://superuser.com/questions/1122396/windows-10-boot-loop-after-update)

Comment: @CodeIt unlike that question, his PC isn't 'crashing' just hanging at the loading

Comment: @YisroelTech It's a possible duplicate not exact duplicate. Friend please see this [answer](http://superuser.com/a/1122612/383350).

Comment: To me, it's a dead hard-drive

Comment: @YisroelTech Yes I use both a wireless mouse and a keyboard

Comment: @books453, then try unplugging both of them and try turning on the PC. See of it does boot that way.

Comment: @YisroelTech Nope, it didn't change anything.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've provided enough evidence that this question isn't a duplicate, so can someone remove the "This question may already have an answer here..."

Comment: @CodeIt Shouldn't that first comment you made be an answer?

Comment: @books453, you added to the question that you "tried turning off" the wireless keyboard and mouse. What I advised was unplugging the piece in the PC (USB) that is the connector for those. Is this what you did, if you just turned off the devices then try the way I said, to "unplug" the connector/s completely and then attempt to start the computer.

Comment: @YisroelTech I have a bluetooth keyboard and mouse(they came with the computer when I bought it), not one with a usb reciever.

Comment: @books453, Oh, I see. The reason I wanted you to try this is because wireless mice and keyboards are known to sometimes prevent systems from booting after updates. You may try to disable Bluetooth in the BIOS settings.

Comment: @CodeIt the video you mentioned didn't work